# how to mock AutoMapper in ASP.NET MVC Unit Tests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, automapper

I've used AutoMapper in my controller for mapping my Model objects to my ViewModel objects.
A IMappingEngine object is injected in my controllers by Unity and the Mapping configuration is done in the global.asax.

In my controller's unit tests, how should I mock the IMappingEngine passed as parameter in the constructor  ?

Do I have to setup all the mapping configuration again in the unit test project ?

Comment: Can you add some sample code that illustrates your dilemma? That will make it easier to give you a good answer. Also, what mocking library are you using in your tests?

Answer (score 1):

If you are abstracting AutoMapper through the use of an interface the point of this is so that you do NOT have to use AutoMapper in your unit test. It is a unit test so you are testing just the code in the controller action. All you need to do is use a mocking framework like RhinoMocks or Moq and mock the behaviour you need for your test. With RhinoMocks you would have something like this:

```
var mapper= MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMappingEngine>();
```

and then use mapper.Stub to add the behaviour you need.

Comment: ok, that's seem to be what I'm looking for. However I'm a bit confused with the mapper.Stub part... Do I basically pass it the output that I would normally expect from Automapper, so that the controller can be tested without automapper ?

Comment: Exactly right, you make the stub perform like you would expect AutoMapper to normally behave.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you injecting AutoMapper in the first place?

What are your tests suppose to test since the output of your controller (ViewModels) is dependent on the mappings?

I suspect you have a bit too much abstractions in your code. There is nothing wrong with using the AutoMapper directly.

Comment: Probably it's to avoid using Mapper as a static class when mapping, which seems to have been one of the regrets of the AutoMapper's creator and marked as obsolete.
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/